# Regex error using MSVC 2013

Tags: c++, regex, visual-c++, std

I have a piece of xml like code to parse, using std::regex in MSVC 2013

```
<GLVertex>
#version 450 core
layout(location = 0) in vec3 pos;
in VertexInfo{
    vec2 uv;
}vertexInfo;
void main(){
    gl_Position = vec4(pos, 1.0);
    vertexInfo.uv = pos.xy;
}
<GLVertex/>
<GLFragment>
#version 450 core
layout(location = 0) uniform sampler2D g_map;
uniform Color {
    vec4 color;
};
layout(location = 0) out vec4 fragColor;
void main(){
    fragColor = texture(g_map, vertexInfo.uv);
}
<GLFragment/>
```

Here is the pattern:

```
<GLVertex>((.|\n)+)<GLVertex\/>
```

But the program always crash! Is there any bug in my regex? I've tested on regex101.

PS. when i delete the 5th line:

```
vec2 uv;
```

it works OK!

Comment: Please see this [link](http://ideone.com/scAA2F ).

Comment: seems like it's a bug of MSVC stdlib...@Praveen

Comment: still crashed, thanks anyway @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: I guess you try with the *Debug* mode, switch to the *Release* one. Also, see my answer below, and I advise reading the article I linked to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get a `Stack overflow (parameters: 0x00000001, 0x00312FFC)` exception as the pattern is not efficient. I think it is related to how `std::regex` processes repeated groups (you have define one with a `+`-quantifier group `(.|\n)+`). This pattern matches each and every character that is not a newline (`.`), or a newline (`\n`), and then stores the match inside a buffer. Then, an issue with the iterator debugging happens **only in *Debug* mode**. The `std::_Orphan_Me` is the place where the break occurs, and it is considered the most "expensive" method when matching strings. See [*performance killer -Debug Iterator Support in Visual studio*](https://benc45.wordpress.com/2008/07/13/performance-killer-debug-iterator-support-in-visual-studio/)

You should either switch to the *Release* mode, or test with a regex that does not require the use of the repeated groups, like *any non-null character* `[^\x00]` with lazy quantifier `*?`:

```
std::string str1 = "<GLVertex>\n#version 450 core\nlayout(location = 0) in vec3 pos;\nin VertexInfo{\n    vec2 uv;\n}vertexInfo;\nvoid main(){\n    gl_Position = vec4(pos, 1.0);\n    vertexInfo.uv = pos.xy;\n}\n<GLVertex/>\n<GLFragment>\n#version 450 core\nlayout(location = 0) uniform sampler2D g_map;\nuniform Color {\n    vec4 color;\n};\nlayout(location = 0) out vec4 fragColor;\nvoid main(){\n    fragColor = texture(g_map, vertexInfo.uv);\n}\n<GLFragment/>"; 
std::regex reg1("<GLVertex>([^\\x00]*?)<GLVertex/>");
std::smatch find1;
if (std::regex_search(str1, find1, reg1)){
    std::cout << find1[1].str();
}
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome! And thank you for you patience! Seems I have much to learn.